# Use Webhooks to get data into Hubspot from a scheduling app that Zapier doesn't currently have listed

Tags: automation, webhooks, zapier, hubspot

My company uses Hubspot as their CRM and a software called PTEverywhere for scheduling and billing. These two softwares don't talk to each other, so we're having to do a lot of manual data entry. I am looking for a solution in Zapier and I believe Webhooks are the answer. PTEverywhere has an open API and mentions Webhooks in its documentation. I can't seem to find any resources that actually help me understand *how* to set this connection up. Does anybody know of any good resources to help me learn this? Or possibly even different solutions I should consider?

I have researched this for days now and every video I find does a great job explaining what I want to be able to do, but when it gets to the part where they actually do it, they skip a *ton* of steps and underexplain.